# Why can't I valign top inside H1 with doctype html

Tags: html-table

```
<!DOCTYPE html><html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<table border=1><tr><td>iasdfasdfa<br>asdfasdfasdf<br>asdfasdfasdf<br>asdfasdf</td><td valign=top style='vertical-align: top;'><h1>This Text Won't Valign Top</h1></td></tr></table>
```

Answer (score 0):

It does align to the top. It's just that the `<h1>` element has a default margin that's pushing it down. Remove it:

```css
h1 {
  margin: 0
}
```

```html
<table border=1>
  <tr>
    <td>iasdfasdfa
      <br>asdfasdfasdf
      <br>asdfasdfasdf
      <br>asdfasdf</td>
    <td style='vertical-align: top;'>
      <h1>This Text Won't Valign Top</h1></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Note: Don't use `valign=top` as that's been deprecated for ages.